# Markdown not interpreted by Ruby redcarpet correctly

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redcarpet, slate

I have a following markdown for my [`slate`](https://github.com/tripit/slate) project:

````
---
title: API Reference
language_tabs:
  - http
  - javascript
search: true
---
# Getting Started
## Logout
# Call Management
## Call States
```javascript
{
}
```
## Call Notification
## Caller ID Called Number
## Call Information During Call
````

And I use `middleman` to serve a site: `bundle exec middleman server`. However, the last subsection title is not interpreted correctly as a `h2` tag (screenshot). The result is the same if I build it through `rake build`.

**However, if I put this markdown on other interpreters like http://stackedit.io, it is fine.**

So I suspect that my markdown interpreter ([Ruby redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet)) is broken somehow. I did not get any warning/error message on the console. I tried different versions of redcarpet. The interpreted HTML is also erroneous, although errors are different. I suppose some combination of Ruby and Redcarpet will make it?

Here is my `config.rb`:

```
# Markdown
set :markdown_engine, :redcarpet
set :markdown,
fenced_code_blocks: true,
smartypants: true,
disable_indented_code_blocks: true,
prettify: true,
tables: true,
with_toc_data: true,
no_intra_emphasis: true
```

Could anybody tell what the probable cause is? Or how to recover?

[image]

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem on my computer, with the same Gemfile. Did you change the `slate` engine somehow? Usually the code snippets are shown in another column with `slate`.

Comment: Your markdown compiles just fine for me. I just had to comment `therubyracer` gem since it's causing some hanging issues for me (and install `nodejs` package instead).

Comment: @AlexeyShein I am on Win7 x64. I am pretty sure that the markdown syntax is correct, because other interpreters work well. I just want to get some hint, at least, about where the probable cause is? Log file, or reinstall which gem, what so ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the newest version [(3.3.3)](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/releases/tag/v3.3.3) of RedCarpet solved my problem.

---

#### Update 1

Well, it still has problems: I cannot change even a single letter inside the Markdown file. Otherwise, the generated HTML markup screws up again...

---

#### Update 2

Finally solved. Switching [RedCarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) to [kramdown](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown) solved it.

My `config.rb`:

```
# set :markdown_engine, :redcarpet
set :markdown_engine, :kramdown
set :markdown,
    fenced_code_blocks: true,
    smartypants: true,
    disable_indented_code_blocks: true,
    prettify: true,
    tables: true,
    with_toc_data: true,
    no_intra_emphasis: true
```